# Elementwise product between a vector and a matrix using GNU Blas subroutines

Tags: c, vector, gnu, blas, elementwise-operations

I am working on C, using GNU library for scientific computing. Essentially, I need to do the equivalent of the following MATLAB code:

```
x=x.*(A*x);
```

where x is a gsl_vector, and A is a gsl_matrix.

I managed to do (A*x) with the following command:

```
gsl_blas_dgemv(CblasNoTrans, 1.0, A, x, 1.0, res);
```

where res is an another gsl_vector, which stores the result. If the matrix A has size m * m, and vector x has size m * 1, then vector res will have size m * 1.

Now, what remains to be done is the elementwise product of vectors x and res (the results should be a vector). Unfortunately, I am stuck on this and cannot find the function which does that.

If anyone can help me on that, I would be very grateful. In addition, does anyone know if there is some better documentation of GNU rather than https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/GSL-BLAS-Interface.html#GSL-BLAS-Interface which so far is confusing me.

Finally, would I lose in time performance if I do this step by simply using a for loop (the size of the vector is around 11000 and this step will be repeated 500-5000 times)?

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    gsl_vector_set(res, i, gsl_vector_get(x, i) * gsl_vector_get(res, i));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you want is:

```
gsl_vector_mul(res, x)
```

I have used Intel's MKL, and I like the documentation on their website for these BLAS routines.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be working exactly as I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop is ok if GSL is well designed. For example `gsl_vector_set()` and `gsl_vector_get()` can be inlined. You could compare the running time with `gsl_blas_daxpy`. The for-loop is well optimized if the timing result is similar.

On the other hand, you may want to try a much better matrix library [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), with which you can implement your operation with the code similar to this

```
x = x.array() * (A * x).array();
```